# I want to pass an ID as a params with Vue Router, but I'm having trouble

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router, router

I have an article view and sideBarRight component.

In SideBarRight Component -

```
<v-chip-group>
     <v-chip v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag" :item-id="tag.id" @click="chipClick(tag.id)">
     {{ tag.articleName }}
     </v-chip>
</v-chip-group>
.
.
.
methods:{
   chipClick(itemId) {
      this.$router.push({name: 'article', params: { itemId }});
      }
}
```

and my router shown below:

```
{
     path: "/article/:itemId",
     name: "article",
     component: () =>
         import("../views/ArticleView.vue")
}
```

I want to navigate upon clicking on chips and pass the itemId to the view. I'm not sure how to achieve this. Is there a specific hook for that?

Comment: route params will be accessible from a component as `this.$route.params`

Comment: `this.$router.push( { name: 'article', params: { itemId: itemId } } );`

Comment: I already did this. The parameters are accessed to the `beforeRouteEntered` successfully. However, it is not triggered on every route.
 ```data():{
     return {
          content: ""
      }
},
beforeRouteEntered(to, from, next){
      // I get the data from api and I pass the html content but 
      this.content = apiResult.data.content;  // but this is not worked. 
}```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77455826/edit) your question to include new code.  It is hard to read unformatted code in a comment.

Comment: It sounds like the question is answered, as you are accessing params in your component successfully.  Now you have a new problem, so should be new question, however it looks simple enough.  `this.content` inside of a component route guard is incorrect.  Check the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#Using-the-options-API) - "beforeRouteEnter() ... does NOT have access to `this` component instance".  Simply put the code in some other hook, e.g. `created()` or `mounted()`